# "DLL load failed while importing <module>: specified procedure not found" in all but the default anaconda environment

Tags: python, python-import, dllimport

I want to import a python module (in the form of .pyd files for python 3.6 until 3.11) that is the API of a program I'm using. The import will fail with the message mentioned in the title except in my old Anaconda 2022-10's base environment. New environments, even with the same Python version (3.9.13), give the same error.

Dependencies reports only the Python3xx.dll missing but that should be available from the conda environment.

Is there any way to debug this? How can I find out which procedure is the problem?